# How to integrate react native with Facebook Pixel

Tags: reactjs, react-native, facebook, facebook-pixel

I've been searching for a while now trying to find out docs on how to set up Facebook pixel with an existing react native app is there is package that does that or anyone with experience doing that can help me.

Comment: Ever figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: Can't believe that integrating two Facebook technologies is near impossible to find on the Internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Facebook Pixel](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/meta-pixel/get-started)'s docs, Pixel is available only on websites.
To track events in mobile apps, you could use [App Events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/overview).

Regarding React Native, [Facebook ended its official support for their wrapper](https://github.com/facebookarchive/react-native-fbsdk/blob/master/README.md), but you can use the community maintained [react-native-fbsdk-next](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next) library, as also suggested by Facebook itself. Specifically, to track analytics events, you can use the [AppEventsLogger](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next#app-events-1).

Comment: So Facebook has ended support for the SDK wrapper, but nowhere is there clear documentation on. how to use a React-Native app (from Facebook none the less) with App Events (also from Facebook) 
I don't get it. What's a developer supposed to do ?

Comment: According to [official Facebook fbsdk README](https://github.com/facebookarchive/react-native-fbsdk/blob/master/README.md), they suggest to use [react-native-fbsdk-next](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next). There you can find instruction on how to set it up and make it work in your app